# Residential electrical panel

Tags: electrical-panel

While replacing a breaker I found 2 #10 wires coming off the line side of the main breaker besides the main feeder wires. What would this be for and is it safe?

Comment: Does your house have solar panels?

Comment: Also, adding a picture would help us figure out what it might be for -- you can edit your post to add them in (it's the little button that looks like a mountain)